# What is dominance in the context of virtual functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, virtual-functions, virtual-inheritance

### Code Sample:

Consider the following diamond hierarchy:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void f(){}
    void g(){}
};    
struct B : virtual A
{
    virtual void f() override{}
    void g(){}
};     
struct C : virtual A
{   
};    
struct D: B, C
{    
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.f(); //B::f is called
    d.g(); //B::g is called
}
```

### What I Do Understand:

As far as the non-virtual function `g` is concerned, everything is clear: the name `B::g` hides `A::g`, even though the name `A::g` could be reached without being hidden through `C`. There is no ambiguity. `B::g` is called. [The standard](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf) explicitly confirms this in 10.2 p.10:

> [ Note: When virtual base classes are used, a hidden declaration can be reached along a path through the
>   subobject lattice that does not pass through the hiding declaration. This is not an ambiguity. The identical
>   use with non-virtual base classes is an ambiguity; in that case there is no unique instance of the name that
>   hides all the others. — end note ] [Example:

Additionally, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7211847/469935) to a related question provided an exhaustive explanation of the issue.

### The Problem:

What I don't understand is how the quote mentioned above pertains to the virtual function `f`. There is no name hiding involved with `f`, is there? Only overriding is involved, and 10.3 p.2 reads:

> A virtual member function C::vf of a class object S is a final
>   overrider unless the most derived class (1.8) of which S is a base
>   class subobject (if any) declares or inherits another member function
>   that overrides vf. In a derived class, if a virtual member function of
>   a base class subobject has more than one final overrider the program
>   is ill-formed.

Now, it seems to me, that the virtual function `f` exactly fits the definition of *not* having a final overrider and the program should be ill-formed. But it's not. Or is it? MSVC compiles it just fine, with the following warning:

> warning C4250: 'D' : inherits 'B::B::f' via dominance

To be honest, I had never come across the term "dominance" before. When I search it in the standard, it has a single occurrence, in the index, and refers me to the chapter where my first quote comes from. And, as I already mentioned, the quote seems to pertain only to name hiding rather than virtual function overriding.

### Questions:

- Does `f` have more than one final overrider in D?
- Does the rule of *dominance* apply in this case? How does it follow from the standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll quote `[10.3]/2` again:

> A virtual member function `C::vf` of a class object `S` is a *final overrider* unless the most derived class (1.8) of which `S` is a base class subobject (if any) declares or inherits another member function that overrides `vf`. In a derived class, if a virtual member function of a base class subobject has more than one final overrider the program is ill-formed.

So in your example `A::f` is not a final overrider, because `D` (the most derived class) inherits `B::f` which overrides it. `B::f` is a final overrider, and so it is called.

The program would be ill-formed if there were more than one final overrider (for example if `C` also overrode `f`), but there is only one, so everything is fine.

Clang and GCC compile this [without a single warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08503328f6be1147).

Answering your question, [the documentation on C4250 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b3sy7ae.aspx) describes exactly your situation, and by dominance it apparently means the behavior described in `[10.3]/2`.

Comment: What is `C::f()` called? - it doesn't count as a virtual member function? (being inherited from A)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I don't understand the question. Class `C` doesn't override `f`.

Comment: You can call `C::f()`, `C` inherits it from `A` without overriding

Comment: @MattMcNabb So you mean `D d; d.C::f();`? Yes it will call `A::f()` according to `5.2.2/1` (it's found by usual overload resolution rules)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: There is no function `C::f` but looking up `f` in the scope of `C` finds `A::f`. There's a subtle distinction in C++ between a scope containing `foo` and being able to find `foo` in that scope.

Comment: @MattMcNabb "_What is C::f() called?_" `C::f` is `A::f` and is called a hidden name in `D`